# List of Definitions, List of Theorems, List of Examples, and List of Activities with Kaobook

Tags: table-of-contents, environments, books, exercises, kaobook

This is somewhat a follow-up to [this question about custom Kaobook environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603869/custom-example-environment-with-colorbox-and-vertical-line-for-kaobook-documen/604560?noredirect=1#comment1516573_604560). In that question, I was able to successfully define some new environments for the `kaobook` class and have them all share numbering:

[image]

**Goal**

I would like to issue commands::

- `\listofdefinitions`
- `\listoftheorems`
- `\listofexamples`
- `\listofactivities`

to automatically generate lists in the table of contents, similar to the existing commands

- `\tableofcontents`
- `\listoffigures`
- `\listoftables`.

**Some things I tried:**

1.) Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309690/list-of-algorithms-with-tufte-book), I tried

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\listofdefinitions}{%
  \let\l@definition\l@figure
  \chapter*{\listdefinitionname}%
  \@starttoc{loa}%
}
\makeatother
```

but this did not work and issued an error.

2.) Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43311/formatting-new-list-of-definitions-with-tocloft), I also tried

```
\newcommand{\listdefinitionname}{My list of definitions}
\newlistof{definition}{def}{\listdefinitionname}
\newcommand{\definition}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{definition}%
  \par\noindent\textbf{The Definition~\thedefinition. #1}%
  \addcontentsline{def}{figure}
    {\protect\numberline{\thechapter.\thedefinition}#1}\par%
}
\makeatletter
```

but this also issued an error, saying `definition` is already defined.

3.) I read that the [`thmtools` package](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/thmtools/doc/thmtools-manual.pdf) has a `\listoftheorems` command, which I tried to use, but it lists everything together under the same heading:

[image]

As you can see, there are a few problems:

- Definitions and Theorems are grouped together - I would like separate lists for each environment type
- Activities and Examples are missing (?)
- The "label" of each definition, theorem, etc. is not displayed.
- The end-of-section `exercises` are showing in the list.

Any ideas how to fix these problems? If it helps, here is a link to the [Overleaf project](https://www.overleaf.com/3212563377jyzdcgshhhbn). Feel free to play around with the code.

**`main.tex`**

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=10pt, % Base font size
    twoside=false, % Use different layouts for even and odd pages (in particular, if twoside=true, the margin column will be always on the outside)
    %open=any, % If twoside=true, uncomment this to force new chapters to start on any page, not only on right (odd) pages
    %chapterprefix=true, % Uncomment to use the word "Chapter" before chapter numbers everywhere they appear
    %chapterentrydots=true, % Uncomment to output dots from the chapter name to the page number in the table of contents
    numbers=noenddot, % Comment to output dots after chapter numbers; the most common values for this option are: enddot, noenddot and auto (see the KOMAScript documentation for an in-depth explanation)
    %draft=true, % If uncommented, rulers will be added in the header and footer
    %overfullrule=true, % If uncommented, overly long lines will be marked by a black box; useful for correcting spacing problems
]{kaobook}

% Set the language
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Load characters and hyphenation
\usepackage[english=british]{csquotes} % English quotes

% Load mathematical packages for theorems and related environments. NOTE: choose only one between 'mdftheorems' and 'plaintheorems'.
\usepackage{styles/mdftheorems}
%\usepackage{styles/plaintheorems}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369265/math-book-how-to-write-exercise-and-answers
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{lightcyan}{cyan!40!white}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[skins,hooks,xparse,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftheorems
\chapter{Chapter Name}
\section{Section}

\begin{activity}[Name of Activity 1][activity:activityname]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{activity}

\begin{definition}\labdef{Name of Definition 2}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}\label{Name of Theorem 3}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{theorem}

\begin{bookexample}[Name of Example 3][ex:example_4]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{bookexample}

Referring to Example \ref{ex:example_4}.

\begin{solution}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{solution}

\begin{definition} \labdef{Name of Definition 5}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem} \label{Name of Theorem 6}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{theorem}

\begin{bookexample}[Name of Example 7][ex:example_7]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{bookexample}

\begin{solution}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{solution}

\newpage

\begin{Exercise}\label{EX11}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}% <-- You don't need this line of code if there's some text here
\Question Multiple choice question
\settasks{label={(\Alph*)}}
\begin{tasks}(4)
\task Choice 1
\task Choice 2
\task Choice 3
\task\label{correctchoice_1.1.1} Choice 4
\end{tasks}

\Question Multiple choice question
\settasks{label={(\Alph*)}}
\begin{tasks}(4)
\task Choice 1
\task Choice 2
\task\label{correctchoice_1.1.2} Choice 3
\task Choice 4
\end{tasks}

\Question Multi-part question
\settasks{label={\roman*.}}
\begin{tasks}(1)
\task Part 1
\task Part 2
\task Part 3
\end{tasks}
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}[ref={EX11}]
\Question This is a solution of Ex 1
\end{Answer}
\setboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}{false}
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit 7/24:**

Now also including `environments.sty` and `mdftheorems.sty`, where some of the kaobox environments are defined. (Sorry, I am new to this [Overleaf Kaobook template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/kaobook) and didn't know it had these dependencies spread across multiple files.) I do not know how these 2 files work, so I am going to paste them as-is.

**`environments.sty`**

```
%% environments.sty
%% Copyright 2020 Federico Marotta
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Federico Marotta
%
% This work consists of all the files listed in MANIFEST.md.

\ProvidesPackage{styles/environments}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ITEMS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\small$\blacktriangleright$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\textbullet}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep}
\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep}
\setlist[description]{noitemsep}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SIMPLE BOXED ENVIRONMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% kaobox (while tcolorbox may be more rich, I find it too complicated so I prefer mdframed)
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

%\mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=0pt}
\mdfdefinestyle{kaoboxstyle}{
    skipabove=1.5\topskip,
    skipbelow=.5\topskip,
    rightmargin=0pt,
    leftmargin=0pt,
    %innertopmargin=3pt,
    %innerbottommargin=3pt,
    innerrightmargin=7pt,
    innerleftmargin=7pt,
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    rightline=false,
    leftline=false,
    %linewidth=1pt,
    %roundcorner=0pt,
    %font={},
    %frametitlefont={},
    frametitlerule=true,
    linecolor=black,
    %backgroundcolor=LightBlue,
    fontcolor=black,
    %frametitlebackgroundcolor=LightBlue,
}

\newmdenv[
    style=kaoboxstyle,
    backgroundcolor=RoyalBlue!20!White,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=RoyalBlue!20!White,
]{kaobox}

\newmdenv[
    style=kaoboxstyle,
    backgroundcolor=Cyan!15!White,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=Cyan!15!White,
]{objective}

\newmdenv[
    style=kaoboxstyle,
    backgroundcolor=Green!15!White,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=Green!15!White,
    frametitle=Solution,
]{solution}

\newmdenv[
    style=kaoboxstyle,
    backgroundcolor=Gray!15!White,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=Gray!15!White,
    frametitle=Proof,
]{kaoproof}

\newmdenv[
    style=kaoboxstyle,
    backgroundcolor=Magenta!15!White,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=Magenta!15!White,
]{note}

\newmdenv[
    style=kaoboxstyle,
    backgroundcolor=Purple!15!White,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=Purple!15!White,
    frametitle=Summary
]{summary}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ENVIRONMENT WITH A COUNTER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{kaocounter}{
    \refstepcounter{kaocounter}
    \begin{kaobox}[frametitle=Comment~\thekaocounter\autodot]
}{
    \end{kaobox}
}

\newcounter{kaocounter}
\numberwithin{kaocounter}{section}
\newcommand*{\kaocounterformat}{% Format for the caption
    Comment~\thekaocounter\csname autodot\endcsname}
\newcommand*{\fnum@kaocounter}{\kaocounterformat}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FLOATING ENVIRONMENT WITH TOC ENTRIES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{kaofloating}{%
    \@float{kaofloating}%
}{%
    \end@float%
}

\newcommand*{\fps@floatingbox}{tbph}
\newcommand*{\ftype@floatingbox}{5}
\newcommand*{\floatingboxformat}{%
    Insight~\thefloatingbox\csname autodot\endcsname}
\newcommand*{\fnum@floatingbox}{\floatingboxformat}
\newcommand*{\ext@floatingbox}{loi}

\addtotoclist[float]{loi}
\newcommand*{\listofloiname}{List of Insights}
\newcommand*{\l@floatingbox}{\l@figure}
\newcommand*{\listofinsights}{\listoftoc{loi}}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603869/custom-example-environment-with-colorbox-and-vertical-line-for-kaobook-documen
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[skins,hooks,xparse,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

% comment this line during integration because kaocounter would have been declared
%\newcounter{kaocounter}
% you may not need the line below as well if it has already been configured using other approaches
\counterwithin{kaocounter}{section}
\definecolor{greentitle}{RGB}{61,170,61}
\definecolor{greentitleback}{RGB}{216,233,213}
\definecolor{drakgreentitle}{RGB}{24,131,80}

\DeclareTColorBox{bookexample}{O{}o}{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    arc=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    colframe=white,
    colback=white,
    top=3em, % you can change the top spacing
    overlay unbroken and first={
        % draw box on the left
        \node[fill=greentitleback,
            font=\color{greentitle}\sffamily\bfseries\large,
            anchor=south west,
            inner sep=3pt,
            left=2mm,
            right=2mm,
            xshift=1mm,
            yshift=-2em, % you can change xshift and yshift to adjust the title placement
        ] (titlebox) at (frame.north west) 
        % notice the difference here, kaocounter is used instead
        {Example \refstepcounter{theorem}\thetheorem
        % add cross-referencing support
        \IfValueT{#2}{\label{#2}}
        };
        
        % write title on the right
        \node[font=\color{drakgreentitle}\sffamily\large, 
        anchor=west
        ] at ($(titlebox.east)+(2mm,0mm)$) {#1};
        
        % draw the vertical line on the left
        \draw[draw=greentitleback, line width=2pt] 
            (titlebox.north west-|frame.north west)--(frame.south west);
    },
    overlay middle and last={
        \draw[draw=greentitleback, line width=2pt] 
            (frame.north west)--(frame.south west);
    }
    fonttitle=\color{greentitle}\sffamily\bfseries\large,
}

\DeclareTColorBox{genericbox}{m}{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    arc=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    colback=white,
    attach boxed title to top left,
    boxed title style={
        colback=white,
        colframe=white,
    },
    title={#1},
    fonttitle=\color{greentitle}\sffamily\bfseries\large
}

\DeclareTColorBox{activity}{O{}o}{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    arc=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    colframe=white,
    colback=white,
    top=3em, % you can change the top spacing
    overlay unbroken and first={
        % draw box on the left
        \node[fill=Cyan!15!White,
            font=\color{Cyan}\sffamily\bfseries\large,
            anchor=south west,
            inner sep=3pt,
            left=2mm,
            right=2mm,
            xshift=1mm,
            yshift=-2em, % you can change xshift and yshift to adjust the title placement
        ] (titlebox) at (frame.north west) 
        % notice the difference here, kaocounter is used instead
        {Activity \refstepcounter{theorem}\thetheorem
        % add cross-referencing support
        \IfValueT{#2}{\label{#2}}
        };
        
        % write title on the right
        \node[font=\color{Cyan}\sffamily\large, 
        anchor=west
        ] at ($(titlebox.east)+(2mm,0mm)$) {#1};
        
        % draw the vertical line on the left
        \draw[draw=Cyan!15!White, line width=2pt] 
            (titlebox.north west-|frame.north west)--(frame.south west);
    },
    overlay middle and last={
        \draw[draw=Cyan!15!White, line width=2pt] 
            (frame.north west)--(frame.south west);
    }
    fonttitle=\color{Cyan}\sffamily\bfseries\large,
}

\DeclareTColorBox{genericbox}{m}{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    arc=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    colback=white,
    attach boxed title to top left,
    boxed title style={
        colback=white,
        colframe=white,
    },
    title={#1},
    fonttitle=\color{greentitle}\sffamily\bfseries\large
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369265/math-book-how-to-write-exercise-and-answers
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{tasks}
\newlength{\longestlabel}
\settowidth{\longestlabel}{\bfseries viii.}
\settasks{label={(\Alph*)}, label-format={\bfseries}, label-width=\longestlabel,
    item-indent=20pt, label-offset=2pt, column-sep={10pt}}
\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed]{exercise}
\counterwithin{Exercise}{chapter}
\counterwithin{Answer}{chapter}
\renewcounter{Exercise}[chapter]
\newcommand{\QuestionNB}{\bfseries\arabic{Question}.\ }
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{EXERCISES}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\noindent\def\stackalignment{l}% code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195118/101651
    \stackunder[0pt]{\colorbox{cyan}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{\LARGE\ExerciseHeaderNB\;\large\ExerciseName}}}}{\textcolor{lightcyan}{\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}}\medskip}
\renewcommand{\AnswerName}{Exercises}
\renewcommand{\AnswerHeader}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{firstanswerofthechapter}}%
    {\bigskip\noindent\textcolor{cyan}{\textbf{CHAPTER \thechapter}}\newline\newline%
        \noindent\bfseries\emph{\textcolor{cyan}{\AnswerName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB, page %
                \pageref{\AnswerRef}}}\smallskip}
    {\noindent\bfseries\emph{\textcolor{cyan}{\AnswerName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB, page \pageref{\AnswerRef}}}\smallskip}}
\setlength{\QuestionIndent}{16pt}
```

**`mdftheorems.sty`**

```
%% mdftheorems.sty
%% Copyright 2020 Federico Marotta
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Federico Marotta
%
% This work consists of all the files listed in MANIFEST.md.

\ProvidesPackage{styles/mdftheorems}

% Use mdframed to shade the background of theorems

\let\openbox\relax
\usepackage{amsmath} % Improved mathematics
\usepackage{amsfonts} % Mathematical fonts
\usepackage{amssymb} % AMS symbols and environments
\usepackage{amsthm} % Mathematical environments
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

% Box style
\mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=0pt}%-.5\topskip}
\mdfdefinestyle{mdfkao}{
    skipabove=\topskip,
    skipbelow=\topskip, % Does not work :(
    rightmargin=0pt,
    leftmargin=0pt,
    innertopmargin=7pt,
    innerbottommargin=3pt,
    innerrightmargin=5pt,
    innerleftmargin=5pt,
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    rightline=false,
    leftline=false,
    %linewidth=1pt,
    %roundcorner=0pt,
    %font={},
    %frametitlefont={},
    frametitlerule=true,
    %linecolor=black,
    %backgroundcolor=LightBlue,
    %fontcolor=black,
    %frametitlebackgroundcolor=LightBlue,
}

% Theorem styles
\declaretheoremstyle[
    %spaceabove=.5\thm@preskip,
    %spacebelow=.5\thm@postskip,
    %headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,%\scshape,
    %notefont=\normalfont, notebraces={ (}{)},
    bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
    %headformat={\NAME\space\NUMBER\space\NOTE},
    headpunct={},
    %postheadspace={.5em plus .1em minus .1em},
    %prefoothook={\hfill\qedsymbol}
]{kaoplain}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    %spaceabove=.5\thm@preskip,
    %spacebelow=.5\thm@postskip,
    %headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,%\scshape,
    %notefont=\normalfont, notebraces={ (}{)},
    bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
    %headformat={\NAME\space\NUMBER\space\NOTE},
    headpunct={},
    postheadspace={.5em plus .1em minus .1em},
    %prefoothook={\hfill\qedsymbol}
]{kaodefinition}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    %spaceabove=.5\thm@preskip,
    %spacebelow=.5\thm@postskip,
    %headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
    %notefont=\normalfont, notebraces={ (}{)},
    %bodyfont=\normalfont,
    %headformat={\footnotesize$\triangleright$\space\normalsize\NAME\space\NUMBER\space\NOTE},
    %headformat={\NAME\space\NUMBER\space\NOTE},
    headpunct={},
    postheadspace={.5em plus .1em minus .1em},
    %refname={theorem,theorems},
    %Refname={Theorem,Theorems},
]{kaoremark}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    %spaceabove=.5\thm@preskip,
    %spacebelow=.5\thm@postskip,
    %headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
    %notefont=\normalfont, notebraces={ (}{)},
    %bodyfont=\normalfont,
    %headformat={\NAME\space\NUMBER\space\NOTE},
    headpunct={},
    postheadspace={.5em plus .1em minus .1em},
    %prefoothook={\hfill\qedsymbol}
    %refname={theorem,theorems},
    %Refname={Theorem,Theorems},
]{kaoexample}

\theoremstyle{kaoplain}
\declaretheorem[
    name=Theorem,
    style=kaoplain,
    refname={theorem,theorems},
    Refname={Theorem,Theorems},
    numberwithin=section,
    mdframed={
        style=mdfkao,
        backgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
    },
]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[
    name=Proposition,
    refname={proposition,propositions},
    Refname={Proposition,Propositions},
    sibling=theorem,
    mdframed={
        style=mdfkao,
        backgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
    },
]{proposition}
\declaretheorem[
    name=Lemma,
    refname={lemma,lemmas},
    Refname={Lemma,Lemmas},
    sibling=theorem,
    mdframed={
        style=mdfkao,
        backgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
    },
]{lemma}
\declaretheorem[
    name=Corollary,
    refname={corollary,corollaries},
    Refname={Corollary,Corollaries},
    sibling=theorem,
    mdframed={
        style=mdfkao,
        backgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
    },
]{corollary}

\theoremstyle{kaodefinition}
\declaretheorem[
    name=Definition,
    refname={definition,definitions},
    Refname={Definition,Definitions},
    %numberwithin=section,
    sibling=theorem,
    mdframed={
        style=mdfkao,
        backgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
    },
]{definition}

\theoremstyle{kaoremark}
\declaretheorem[
    name=Remark,
    refname={remark,remarks},
    Refname={Remark,Remarks},
    numberwithin=section,
    mdframed={
        style=mdfkao,
        backgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
    },
]{remark}

\theoremstyle{kaoexample}
\declaretheorem[
    name=Example,
    refname={example,examples},
    Refname={Example,Examples},
    numberwithin=section,
    mdframed={
        style=mdfkao,
        backgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
    },
]{example}

%\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}
%\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{theorem}}
%\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
```

---

**Edit 7/25:** Here is a [link to `kaobook.cls` file](https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook) for those who need it (thanks @cmhughes!) and the [link to the Overleaf project](https://www.overleaf.com/3212563377jyzdcgshhhbn), in case it helps.

Comment: is your example as minimal as possible?

Comment: Where is the activity environment defined? The syntax you are using for it and for the "bookexample" environments suggest that they are defined differently from the other theorem environments, and that they are perhaps defined bypassing `thmtools`, which would explain why they do not show up in the list of theorems. If you want to use `thmtools` you should try to redefine those two environments using the `thmtools` syntax.

Comment: If you are using `thmtools`, the `\listoftheorems` command supports filtering, so you can just list all definitions etc. See section 1.5 of its documentation for details.

Comment: In regards to "the label not being displayed": you are completely misunderstanding what the `\label` command does. It is for cross referencing. If you want to have "named" theorems, you can pass it as an optional argument to the theorem environments. Again, please look at the `thmtools` documentation since it looks like `kaobook` is using `thmtools` under the hood.

Comment: @cmhughes I made the example more minimal.

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you for your advice. I updated the OP with copies of the files `environments.sty` and `mdftheorems.sty`, where these environments seem to me to be defined. I am not sure how these files work.

Comment: @WillieWong I am definitely not stuck on `thmtools`. I only tried that because it looked easy based on another Tex.SE Q&A I read. But it didn't work, and I am definitely open to something else that would work better with `kaobook`'s color box environments for bookexample, activity, definition, theorem, etc.

Comment: for anyone looking at this, it seems that you can get the .cls files from https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook.... I've tried compiling the OP's minimal example, but with no luck.

Comment: Thank you, @cmhughes. The Overleaf link I shared in the OP also contains the `kaobook.cls` file. The problem is, the Kaobook Overleaf template spreads all its dependencies across multiple files. Should I edit the OP to also include the `kaobook.cls` code?

Comment: From `kaobook`'s manual (1.2): "the class is based on KOMA-Script’s scrbook, therefore it inherits all the goodies of that." Note that theorems figures etc in the margins are potentially listable, too.

Comment: The `tocloft` packages does arbitrary user-defined lists of things in the table of contents. Do you want that as a solution-base, or a (higher-level) KOMA-script based solution?

Answer (score 5):

[image: lor]

`kaobook` would classify this request as user-customisation.

So basically, you roll your own.

There are various ways.

Here, a KOMA-script version is shown as proof-of-concept, for one item, the remark. All other items will be clones of this method.

A very brief reading of the manual shows that KOMA-script has a handy command, `\DeclareNewTOC`, which handles all the necessaries for a new TOC list via an environment. Inside this environment, "`\caption` creates
entries for this new content list" (manual, p406).

Here, we will define a non-floating float whose TOC heading will be "List of Remarks" and whose associated ancillary file's extension will be `.rmk`; the base name for associated commands and environments will be `kremark`:

```
\DeclareNewTOC[listname={List of Remarks},
type=kremark,
types=kremarks,
nonfloat,
name=Remark]{rmk}
\setuptoc{rmk}{chapteratlist}
```

The automatically-created nonfloat environment will be called `kremark-`.

Inside this environment will be: (1) the mdframed environment with all its formatting (taken more or less from the OP) called `mdremark`; and (2) a `\caption{}` command:

```
\begin{kremark-}%nonfloat float: KOMA
\begin{mdremark}%md
Text of remark
\caption{\emph{Text of caption}}
\end{mdremark}
\end{kremark-}
```

To save typing, the whole thing can be wrapped inside *another* environment (called, for want of a better name, `myremark`) which can take the caption text as a parameter, and the (multi-par) remark text as its body - easy in expl3 syntax:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myremark}{ m +b }
{
\begin{kremark-}%nonfloat float: KOMA
\begin{mdremark}%md
#2 
\caption{\emph{#1}}
\end{mdremark}
\end{kremark-}
}
{ }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

(`kaobook` already loads `xparse`, and lots of other packages)

Usage:

```
\begin{myremark}{title of remark}
Lorem ipsum ... ullamco laboris\sidenote{Colour is from mdframed; inside a KOMA nonfloating float env; inside a wrapper env which supplies the caption, with caption in turn generating the TOC entry.} 
\end{myremark}
```

Producing:

[image: remark]

Without the wrapper, you would have to type a lot of `\begin...\end`s:

```
\begin{kremark-}
The \verb|kremark| environment, contains the following:
\begin{mdremark}
The \verb|mdremark| environment, with a caption.
\caption{\emph{A bare remark}}
\end{mdremark}
Note the mdframed's colour and other format settings above.
\end{kremark-}
```

Output:

[image: manual remark]

MWE

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=12pt, 
    twoside=false, 
    numbers=noenddot, 
]{kaobook}

\DeclareNewTOC[listname={List of Remarks},
type=kremark,
types=kremarks,
nonfloat,
name=Remark]{rmk}
\setuptoc{rmk}{chapteratlist}

\usepackage{kaotheorems}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{lightcyan}{cyan!40}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

% Box style
\mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=0pt}%-.5\topskip}
\mdfdefinestyle{mdfkao}{
    skipabove=\topskip,
%    skipbelow=\topskip, % Does not work 
    rightmargin=0pt,
    leftmargin=0pt,
    innertopmargin=7pt,
    innerbottommargin=3pt,
    innerrightmargin=5pt,
    innerleftmargin=5pt,
%%    topline=false,
%%    bottomline=false,
%%    rightline=false,
%%    leftline=false,
    %linewidth=1pt,
    %roundcorner=0pt,
%%    font=\myrfont,
    %frametitlefont={},
    frametitlerule=true,
    %linecolor=black,
    %backgroundcolor=LightBlue,
    %fontcolor=black,
    %frametitlebackgroundcolor=LightBlue,
middlelinecolor=red!15,
middlelinewidth=1.5pt,
backgroundcolor=red!2,
roundcorner=10pt,    
}

% Theorem styles
\declaretheoremstyle[
    %spaceabove=.5\thm@preskip,
    %spacebelow=.5\thm@postskip,
    %headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,%\scshape,
    %notefont=\normalfont, notebraces={ (}{)},
    bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
    %headformat={\NAME\space\NUMBER\space\NOTE},
    headpunct={},
    %postheadspace={.5em plus .1em minus .1em},
    %prefoothook={\hfill\qedsymbol}
]{kaoplain}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    %spaceabove=.5\thm@preskip,
    %spacebelow=.5\thm@postskip,
    %headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,%\scshape,
    %notefont=\normalfont, notebraces={ (}{)},
    bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
    %headformat={\NAME\space\NUMBER\space\NOTE},
    headpunct={},
    postheadspace={.5em plus .1em minus .1em},
    %prefoothook={\hfill\qedsymbol}
]{kaodefinition}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    %spaceabove=.5\thm@preskip,
    %spacebelow=.5\thm@postskip,
    %headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
    %notefont=\normalfont, notebraces={ (}{)},
    %bodyfont=\normalfont,
    %headformat={\footnotesize$\triangleright$\space\normalsize\NAME\space\NUMBER\space\NOTE},
    %headformat={\NAME\space\NUMBER\space\NOTE},
    headpunct={},
    postheadspace={.5em plus .1em minus .1em},
    %refname={theorem,theorems},
    %Refname={Theorem,Theorems},
]{kaoremark}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    %spaceabove=.5\thm@preskip,
    %spacebelow=.5\thm@postskip,
    %headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
    %notefont=\normalfont, notebraces={ (}{)},
    %bodyfont=\normalfont,
    %headformat={\NAME\space\NUMBER\space\NOTE},
    headpunct={},
    postheadspace={.5em plus .1em minus .1em},
    %prefoothook={\hfill\qedsymbol}
    %refname={theorem,theorems},
    %Refname={Theorem,Theorems},
]{kaoexample}

\theoremstyle{kaoplain}
\declaretheorem[
    name=xTheorem,
    style=kaoplain,
    refname={theorem,theorems},
    Refname={Theorem,Theorems},
    numberwithin=section,
    mdframed={
        style=mdfkao,
        backgroundcolor=Goldenrod!32,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45,
    },
]{xtheorem}

\declaretheorem[
    name=Proposition,
    refname={proposition,propositions},
    Refname={Proposition,Propositions},
    sibling=theorem,
    mdframed={
        style=mdfkao,
        backgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
    },
]{xproposition}

\declaretheorem[
    name=Lemma,
    refname={lemma,lemmas},
    Refname={Lemma,Lemmas},
    sibling=theorem,
    mdframed={
        style=mdfkao,
        backgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
    },
]{xlemma}

\declaretheorem[
    name=Corollary,
    refname={corollary,corollaries},
    Refname={Corollary,Corollaries},
    sibling=theorem,
    mdframed={
        style=mdfkao,
        backgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
    },
]{xcorollary}

\theoremstyle{kaodefinition}
\declaretheorem[
    name=Definition,
    refname={definition,definitions},
    Refname={Definition,Definitions},
    %numberwithin=section,
    sibling=theorem,
    mdframed={
        style=mdfkao,
        backgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45!white,
    },
]{xdefinition}

\theoremstyle{kaoremark}
\declaretheorem[
    name={R},
    refname={remark,remarks},
    Refname={Remark,Remarks},
    numberwithin=section,
    mdframed={
        style=mdfkao,
        backgroundcolor=Goldenrod!12,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=Goldenrod!45,
    },
]{mdremark}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myremark}{ m +b }
{
\begin{kremark-}%nonfloat float: KOMA
\begin{mdremark}%md
#2 
\caption{\emph{#1}}
\end{mdremark}
\end{kremark-}
}
{ }
\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofkremarks

\chapter{Chapter C}
\section{Section S}


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.



\begin{myremark}{title of remark}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris\sidenote{Colour is from mdframed; inside a KOMA nonfloating float env; inside a wrapper env which supplies the caption, with caption in turn generating the TOC entry.} 
\end{myremark}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\begin{myremark}{another remark}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris\sidenote{A second remark.} 
\end{myremark}


\begin{kremark-}
The \verb|kremark| environment, contains the following:
\begin{mdremark}
The \verb|mdremark| environment, with a caption.
\caption{\emph{A bare remark}}
\end{mdremark}
Note the mdframed's colour and other format settings above.
\end{kremark-}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Cicada, thanks for your solution. I am trying to run it but getting some errors. First error: `kaotheorems.sty not found`. I figured this is supposed to be `mdftheorems.sty`, is that correct? I changed the name from `mdftheorems.sty` to `kaotheorems.sty` and moved it out of the styles folder, which seemed to fix the error. Still getting some other errors though, like `LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.` I made a new Overleaf based on your answer: https://www.overleaf.com/4146861246sdygfsmhdmvn

Comment: The github version is different to overleaf setup. I don't know overleaf.

Comment: I can try to make the Overleaf template more like the version you got from Github. Should I rename `mdftheorems.sty` to `kaotheorems.sty`? Or are these supposed to be two separate files?

Comment: I don't know overleaf. It may be the files are named that way for a specific reason. I would recommend asking overleaf, and reading the kaobook documentation.

Comment: I tried @egreg 's solution at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151442/multiple-lists-of-theorems-with-different-titles-any-tex-in-my-case-xelatex with kaobook class, to print a list of definitions: seems to work OK.

Comment: I created a blank Overleaf at https://www.overleaf.com/4146861246sdygfsmhdmvn and pasted your code verbatim into a blank doc and it fails to compile with error `kaotheorems.sty not found`. But I will award the bounty to you because I appreciate the time and effort you spent.

Comment: I was just following the manual instructions of the github kaobook.cls; something similar will be needed for overleaf version, but I don't know overleaf. It could bee overleaf is or is not up-to-date, or adapts kaobook.cls - try asking overleaf about it. Their support is quite good.